# Turning off eslint rule for an interface?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have TypeScript interfaces that I use in Axios and they're ugly since my API requires them in that way:

```
interface MyImage {
  URI: string,
  Width?: number,
  Height?: number,
}
```

Is there a way to disable eslint rule (`naming-convention`) for the whole interface (I have many of them inside one file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the rule at the top of your file by turning the format off for interfaces, try this:

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/naming-convention: ["off", { "selector": "interface", "format": ["camelCase"] }] */
```

---

Original answer:

You'd have to find the rule name that's enforcing the style, I'm guessing it's the `@typescript-eslint/camelcase`.

When you find the rule name, you can turn the rule off for the current file by writing

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Since disabling eslint on each file doesn't seem to be the most convenient approach, you can make some changes in your `.eslintrc` and have it for all files across your project in a more maintainable way.

This has been already answered here:
[Turn off eslint camelCase for typescript interface identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292371/turn-off-eslint-camelcase-for-typescript-interface-identifiers)