# Turn off eslint camelCase for typescript interface identifiers

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to migrate an existing JS repo to TypeScript. The problem is that projects' API responses are objects with identifiers in `snake_case` and this conflicts with default eslint `camelCase` rule.

Before the migration we were handling `snake_case` object identifiers with this rule in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
'camelcase': ['error', {properties: 'never'}],
```

And could have objects like this in our code:

```js
const { variable_name } = await axios(url)
```

But after moving to TypeScript, these identifiers are also going show up in interfaces.

So basically I want to be able to have:

```js
interface Model<T extends string> {
    type: T;
    id: number;
    variable_name: string;
    language_code: string;
}
```

But Typescript now throws:

```
Identifier 'variable_name' is not in camel case.
```

What rule should I have in my `.eslintrc.js` file to justify this? Please note that my identifiers are not limited to those two listed above and there are dozens of others which I removed for simplicity.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, just disable the rule. I've deleted tens of thousands of lines of code acorss multiple codebases that transform API response to camel case for no good reason other than to obey a linter. Sometimes they were plain JS codebases that were being converted to typescript. Sometimes they were TS code bases that use functions like "keysToCamel" which just don't make sense in typescript codebases, because you're casting. Typescript offers your 100x (actually infinite) the security of a camelCase lint rule. The linter works for you, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that JavaScript (for which ESLint is developed) doesn't know of types (eg. interfaces).

So I think this is what is happening while linting the file:

- The `camelCase` rule of ESLint applies to objects and their properties.
- The parser of ESLint doesn't understand that you have an interface and thinks that those are variables within another block. Therefore the check leads to a wrong result.

I think what you need to do is:

- Disable the `camelCase` rule (at least for your TypeScript files).
- Use the [naming-convention](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md) rule instead and configure it as you need.

This should work:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
    "error",
    {
        "selector": "default",
        "format": ["camelCase"]
    },
    {
        "selector": "typeProperty",
        "format": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works but with a few changes. 
I removed the `camelCase` rule and replace it with your `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rules, plus a few others. 
Having `"selector": "default"` rule is not necessary as it breaks everything and  throws new linting errors. 

I can revise your answer with my rules which fixed my problems if you will

Comment: ```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
            "error",
            {
                "selector": "typeProperty",
                "format": null
            },
            {
                "selector": "objectLiteralProperty",
                "format": null
            },
            {
                "selector": "interface",
                "format": ["PascalCase"]
            },
            {
                "selector": "typeParameter",
                "format": ["UPPER_CASE"]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Besides, when use `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"` in your `.eslintrc` file, linter understands typescript and therefore you can have TS-specific selectors

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to mention that you will need to specify a different parser.